# Mapreduce code runnning but not giving desired output

Tags: python-3.x, mapreduce, bigdata

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
mapper1.py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   a=line.split(",")    
   print (a[7])

Rducer1.py
#!/usr/bin/python2

import sys
fcounter=0
mcounter=0
for i in sys.stdin:
    i.strip()
    if i=="Male":
    mcounter+=1
    else:
    fcounter+=1
tot=mcounter+fcounter
print ("Total no. of Candidates:-"+str(tot))        
print ("No. of females:- "+str(fcounter))
print ("No. of males:- "+str(mcounter))
```

[this is output on hadoop cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUucf.png)

Dataset
[Aadhar Card Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oisut.png)

Can anyone Help?? Why i am not getting no. of males right????

Comment: Debug your code. What is the output of `i` on the line `if i=="Male"`?

Comment: how can i debug ?? Can you help? i is iterating in for loop and if i="Male"(string), then increment counter.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/